# What is the solution regarding this issue with wordpress?

Tags: wordpress-theming

After I successfuly creating my website on wordpress offline using xammp,I decided to back it up by using plugin name(All in one backup)to my HDD after some times I want to restore it and its keep on shown me :checking extension compactiblity.

I checked online and found solution that I should extend the maximun size of restoring backup from wordpress, which I did but still the same issue.